# Android: Cache Webview so that can be viewed Offline and be update when Online

Tags: html, android-webview

I've been seeing alot of options but I am suce a beginner and the moste of the code is not just copy and past and work. I understand some of it but not everything.

Been trying to look after something to save/store/cache data from an Online HTML page. When the App goes offline you should be able to still look at the page(App). But if there is any changes on the HTML page the App will download the new changes/updates and cache them.

I have tried with [Cache Manifest](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/how-to-create-offline-webapps-on-the-iphone) (from CSS-Ninja) but didn't work 100%. Had some trouble with the cacheing and offlinemode and when I wanted the new version I want the app to update/refresh it self and don't have any update button.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment, but my rep isn't high enough.

HTML5Rocks.com has a good guide for [getting started with application cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) manifest, and demonstrates how to reload the application when a new version is available.

I have used this technique to achieve what you want. Don't confuse the cache manifest with LocalStorage. See the [Offline Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) overview for more info.